# Getting the SSL certificate fingerprint of smtp.gmail.com

Tags: bash, ssl, openssl, x509certificate, tor

I don't understand why this command is failing

```
openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -in /dev/stdin | cut -d'=' -f2
```

I am trying to initiate a TLS smtp session with the smtp server of Gmail and then redirect the output of the console to the x509 function in order to extract the fingerprint.

Here is what I get when I run the command without filtering the errors

```
$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp < /dev/null
connect: Bad file number
connect:errno=9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that error output consistent? That command worked for me here. Can you ping that host? Can you run `nc -z smtp.gmail.com 587`?

Comment: I dont have the command nc in the shell on the pc I am using. I will try it on my Ubuntu and let you know. ty

Comment: the ping works on the same machine from which that command does not work.

Comment: You might have `netcat` instead of `nc`. You could also try `telnet` if you happen to still have that around.

Comment: I get this: user@user:~$ nc -z smtp.gmail.com 587
user@user:~$. no output in the console

Comment: That's a failure. It should report a success message if it works. It looks like you can't connect to there from your machine. Though I don't quite understand why you got the error message you got.

Comment: I ll try to temporarily disable my firewall.

Comment: Stll no success, even after adding very permissive rules to the firewall. I ll try it again from home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a firewall upstream of my connexion which seems to block my query.
Adding torify at the beginning of the command (I have Tor installed on my computer) solved the issue.

`user@home:~$ torify openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -starttls smtp < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout | cut -d'=' -f2`
`D3:7C:82:FC:D0:5F:8F:D7:DA:A2:59:8C:42:D7:B2:9F:C1:9F:7E:60`

Answer (score 1):

The above sample works perfect with :25 also.

```
openssl s_client -connect some.smtp.host:25 -starttls smtp < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout | cut -d'=' -f2
```